# JSF Upload File not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to call my Controller code from xhtml page. My code is like this to upload a excel file. But, this code is not hitting the Controller. Can anyone help me with fixing this?

```
    <h:form name="addBulkTnForm" id="addBulkTnFormId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGroup id="fileUploadPnGrp">
        <p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{controller.addTnBulkFile}">
        </p:fileUpload>
        <p:commandButton value="Upload" listener="#{controller.addBulkTnUpload}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton> 

        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

Here are my dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured primefaces upload filter from web.xml?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto|native|commons</param-value> <!-- One of these -->
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can check https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf